# Create a http request on local db.json with Angular and a store

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli, store

I'm trying to do a http request on a local db.json file. (with a store, in Angular, using the Angular CLI)
Unfortunately, I have few knowledge:

I will show you a snippet from the code (from the service):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMpw4.png)

It's coming an error when I'm hovering over the code above:

"Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'."

Furthermore, I will show you where my db.json is located:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZU7.png)

In the angular.json I've added the following lines, but it even doesn't work:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiDh8.png)

I don't know how to do a http request on local db.json - files.
I hope anyone can help me with the problem.

Comment: I think HttpClient there is no need to use val.json() it will in val has the JSON Object directly While using Http which is deprecated then we go val.json

Answer (score 0):

The val itself will carry the json requested

and `val => val.<whatever node present in your json>` should work.